# Is it bad to format your ssd many times?

Tags: ssd, disk-format

In the past two years, I have formatted my SSD many times and I started to wonder, is it bad? Does it harm your SSD every time you format?

Answer (score 1):

Formatting your SSD is not particularly different from writing to it. I wouldn't worry about it.

If you'd like to know more about SSD lifetimes, check out this question:[How long will an Apple SSD last?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74497/how-long-will-an-apple-ssd-last)