# Apple Macbook Flash Storage Lifespan

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, storage

I heard that every SSD have a lifespan, so considering Flash Storage on Macbook devices is actually a SSD that is integrated with the logicboard, does it mean when my MBP flash drive reaches its lifespan, my mac will completely unusable? Unless I'm willing to spend a lot of money to buy a logic board replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Check similar question here: [How long will an Apple SSD last?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74497/how-long-will-an-apple-ssd-last)

And here in case you'll need to replace your SSD: http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC